# Why does this struct initialization not work (can't return address of local variable)

Tags: c, pointers, struct

```
Node *create_node() {
    Node node = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    node.cargo = next_free_cargo++;
    return &node;   
}
```

I thought malloc created things on the heap? Why is this still considered a local variable?

Also, is this the correct way?

```
Node *create_node() {
    Node *node = malloc(sizeof(Node*));
    node->cargo = next_free_cargo++;
    return node;    
}
```

As I read it, this creates memory for a pointer to a Node.  But how does it allocate memory for the node itself?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I thought malloc created things on the heap? Why is this still considered a local variable?

[`malloc()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc) does dynamically allocate memory and gives control of the lifetime of the allocated memory to the programmer (until [`free()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/free) is called on the returned pointer). But, this code is incorrect (and the compiler should have [emitted an error](http://ideone.com/xy0h7S)):

```
Node node = malloc(sizeof(Node));
```

as `node` is *not* a pointer, and is allocated on the stack hence the compiler warning about it being a local variable. Change to:

```
Node* node = malloc(sizeof(Node)); /* or malloc(sizeof(*node)); */
if (node)
{
    node->cargo = next_free_cargo++;
}
return node;
```

---

> Also, is this the correct way?

The second snippet is also incorrect as it is only allocating enough memory for a `Node*`, when it needs to allocate memory for a `Node`.

Answer (score 3):

This is the correct way:

```
Node *create_node() {
    Node *node = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    node->cargo = next_free_cargo++;
    return node;    
}
```

The malloc function allocates a memory buffer of sizeof(Node) bytes and it returns a pointer to that memory area. The memory is allocated on heap and it can be referenced after returning from the function. Also the memory for it should be freed when is no longer needed.